# Get/Set value of field in PageBlockTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, salesforce, apex-code

I have a pageBlockTable in a visualforce page, in the table i am allowing users via JQuery .sortable to rearrange the order of the rows.

No, i want to store this sorting on page save, so i have created a new parameter on the product in Salesforce called sort_order that is a number field.

I would like to update the field, which is in the table and will eventually be hidden each time the rows are dragged, so that on save everything is stored.

I have the following code, which i am trying to get to loop through the table and update the fields appropriatley, but i can't work out the JQuery syntax for setting the value of the field.

Here is the code that creates the table:

```
        <apex:pageBlock title="Selected {!$ObjectType.Product2.LabelPlural}" id="selected">
            <apex:variable value="{!1}" var="index">  
            <apex:pageblockTable value="{!shoppingCart}" var="s" id="shopping_cart" rowClasses="cartRow">
                <tr data-SFid="{!index}">


                <apex:column headerValue="{!$ObjectType.OpportunityLineItem.Fields.Description.Label}">
                    <apex:inputField id="item_description" value="{!s.Description}" required="false"/>
                </apex:column>



                <apex:column headerValue="Current ID">
                <apex:inputField id="Current_ID" value="{!s.Sort_Order__c}" style="width:70px" required="false" onkeyup="refreshTotals();"/>
                </apex:column>

                <apex:column headerValue="Updated ID" value="{!index}" />

                <apex:column >
                    <apex:commandLink value="Remove" action="{!removeFromShoppingCart}" reRender="selected,searchResults" immediate="true">
                        <!-- this param is how we send an argument to the controller, so it knows which row we clicked 'remove' on -->
                        <apex:param value="{!s.PriceBookEntryId}" assignTo="{!toUnselect}" name="toUnselect"/>
                    </apex:commandLink>
                    <apex:variable value="{!index+1}" var="index">
                    </apex:variable>
                </apex:column>

                <apex:column headerValue="{!$ObjectType.Product2.LabelPlural}" value="{!s.PriceBookEntry.Product2.Name}"/>




                <apex:column headerValue="{!$ObjectType.OpportunityLineItem.Fields.Quantity.Label}">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!s.Quantity}" style="width:70px" required="true" onkeyup="refreshTotals();"/>
                </apex:column>

                <apex:column headerValue="{!$ObjectType.OpportunityLineItem.Fields.UnitPrice.Label}">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!s.UnitPrice}" style="width:70px" required="true" onkeyup="refreshTotals();"/>
                </apex:column>


               </tr>  
            </apex:pageblockTable>
            </apex:variable>
```

It is the "Current ID" editable field, with the ID of Current_ID that i want to update.

And this is as far as i have gotten with the update script, i have it looping through the rows with the "Selected" id, but i'm not sure how to update/access the value.

```
$( "[id$=shopping_cart] tbody" ).sortable({
                    update: function(event, ui) {
                    //init();
                    i = 0;
                    $("[id$=shopping_cart] tbody tr.cartRow").each(function() {
                          $this = $(this)
                          var value = $(this).find('Current_ID');
                          var value2 = $(value).find('value');
                          console.log("Checking Row " + i);
                          console.log(value);
                          console.log(value2).value;
                          i++;
                          });

    })
```

Help greatly appreciated as i am way more an ObjectiveC person than i am a Javascript/JQuery person!

Thanks

Gareth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$( "[id$=shopping_cart] tbody" ).sortable({
            update: function(event, index) {$("[id$=shopping_cart] tbody tr .cartRow").each(function(index, value) {$(value).val(index); });}
})
```